# How rewrite this JS function to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, function

I'm trying to rewrite this JS function to PHP, but it not works.
I don't know how to do that. Can someone help ?

```js
var node = {"item":1,"children":[{"item":2,"children":[{"item":3,"children":[{"item":4,"children":[]},{"item":5,"children":[]},{"item":6,"children":[{"item":7,"children":[]},{"item":8,"children":[]},{"item":9,"children":[]}]}]},{"item":10,"children":[{"item":11,"children":[]},{"item":12,"children":[{"item":13,"children":[]},{"item":14,"children":[]}]}]}]}]}

 function traverse(node, path = [], result = []){
     if(!node.children.length)
        result.push(path.concat(node.item));
     for(const child of node.children)
         traverse(child, path.concat(node.item), result);
     return result;
 }
 
 console.log(traverse(node));
```

My try in PHP was:

```
$node = json_decode('{"id":1,"children":[{"id":2,"children":[{"id":3,"children":[{"id":4,"children":[]},{"id":5,"children":[]},{"id":6,"children":[{"id":7,"children":[]},{"id":8,"children":[]},{"id":9,"children":[]}]}]},{"id":10,"children":[{"id":11,"children":[]},{"id":12,"children":[{"id":13,"children":[]},{"id":14,"children":[]}]}]}]}]}',true);


 function traverse($node, $path = [], $result = []){
     if(!count($node["children"]))
        $result[] = array_merge($path,$node['id']);
     foreach($node['children'] as $child)
         traverse($child, array_merge($path,$node['id']), $result);
     return $result;
 }
 
print_r(traverse($node));
```

I want same output as JS function return
But in PHP give me errors after my rewrite
https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/115716d78cb1ee025393f3eec8fdc76709fd66ce

Comment: what doesn't work? do you get any errors? what is the current input and output? what is the output you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_merge` expects arrays as argument but `$node['id']` is a number, not an array. You can use `array_merge($path,[$node['id']])` to add a number to an array.

JavaScript passes references by value. For mutable objects this is similar to call-by-reference as long as you don't reassign the reference. In PHP arguments are passed by-value as copies of the objects. You have to pass by reference

```
function traverse($node, $path = [], &$result = [])
```

to copy the behavior:

```
<?php

$node = json_decode('{"id":1,"children":[{"id":2,"children":[{"id":3,"children":[{"id":4,"children":[]},{"id":5,"children":[]},{"id":6,"children":[{"id":7,"children":[]},{"id":8,"children":[]},{"id":9,"children":[]}]}]},{"id":10,"children":[{"id":11,"children":[]},{"id":12,"children":[{"id":13,"children":[]},{"id":14,"children":[]}]}]}]}]}',true);


function traverse($node, $path = [], &$result = []){
    if(!count($node["children"]))
        $result[] = array_merge($path,[$node['id']]);
    foreach($node['children'] as $child)
        traverse($child, array_merge($path,[$node['id']]), $result);
    return $result;
}
 
print_r(traverse($node));
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem with your function is that `array_merge` expects two arrays, first argument is indeed array, but second is number (`$node['id']` is number). Wrap `$node['id']` in array brackets ([ and ]), than you will be merging two arrays.

Here is fixed version:

```
<?php

$node = json_decode('{"id":1,"children":[{"id":2,"children":[{"id":3,"children":[{"id":4,"children":[]},{"id":5,"children":[]},{"id":6,"children":[{"id":7,"children":[]},{"id":8,"children":[]},{"id":9,"children":[]}]}]},{"id":10,"children":[{"id":11,"children":[]},{"id":12,"children":[{"id":13,"children":[]},{"id":14,"children":[]}]}]}]}]}',true);


 function traverse($node, $path = [], $result = []){
     $path[] = $node['id'];
     
     if(!count($node["children"])) {
        $result[] = $path;
     }
     
     foreach($node['children'] as $child) {
         $results = traverse($child, array_merge($path,[$node['id']]), $result);
         $result = array_merge($result, $results);
     }
     
     return $result;
 }
 
print_r(traverse($node));
```

Comment: This helps with errors, but return empty array

Comment: say what you want to do with this function

Comment: I need to iterate through tree structure and get each path of node, as it is in example which you can run, I need it for automatic category operations